# add boxes to a page using a method javascript

Tags: javascript, object, methods

I have an object constructor function here:

```
function Box (id, name, color, number, coordinates) {  
   this.id = id;
   this.name = name;
   this.color = color;
   this.number = number;
   this.coordinates = coordinates;

   this.add = function(howMany) {
   }
  }
```

I have part of a function here where I get a numeric value (5,10 or 15) that the user chooses with a radio button.

```
  function getBoxValues() {
   var nameInput = document.getElementById("name");  
   var name = nameInput.value; 

   var numbersArray = dataForm.elements.amount;
   for (var i = 0; i < numbersArray.length; i++) {
   if (numbersArray[i].checked) {
    number = numbersArray[i].value;

   if (name == null || name == "") {                    
     alert("Please enter a name for your box");
     return;
   }
   else {
    var newbox = new Box("id", name, color, number, "coordinates");  
    boxes.push(newbox);                                       
    addBox(newbox);                                           

   var data = document.getElementById("dataForm");               
    data.reset();
   }
```

Later, I add boxes to the page with this function:

```
  function addBox(newbox) {                                   
   var scene = document.getElementById("scene");              
   var div = document.createElement("div");                   
   div.innerHTML += newbox.name; 
   var x = Math.floor(Math.random() * (scene.offsetWidth-101));
   var y = Math.floor(Math.random() * (scene.offsetHeight-101));
   div.style.left = x + "px";
   div.style.top = y + "px";                        
   scene.appendChild(div);
   newbox.add(number);   
   for (var i = 0; i < howMany; i++) {
   console.log("added"); 
    addBox(newbox);
    }                          
  }
```

My problem is that I want to add the same number of boxes to the web page as the user chooses with the radio button. So far, my console log tells me "added" for the number of times that the value of "number" is looped through. But, I don't know how to change my code so that new boxes are created for the value of number. I am a beginner at this, so I apologize in advance for any confusion. Would appreciate any help.

Comment: this line I question: `scene.appendChild(div) + newbox.add(number);`

Comment: why do you question it? I'm still trying to figure this out, and like I said I'm new at this so it may be obvious to you but it isn't to  me

Comment: appending a child to the DOM, then adding that to a function call(that is not listed) and what is "number", where is that declared? makes no sense - please describe your intent there., number appears to be global with no other detail than this.

Comment: FYI, we COULD jump to the conclusion that newbox = New Box(xxx) but that is NOT listed in your code, and having the this.add() inside that logically does not make sense when you have an id in there, and an id must be unique on every page so syntactically, that would be incorrect.

Comment: number is supposed to be the index value of numbersArray which grabs the value from the radio button that the user chooses. i declare newbox in the same function getBoxValues(). howMany is supposed to be the argument that i pass through the add method and passes the value of number into the for loop that is supposed to be creating the boxes.

Answer (score 0):

```
function addBoxes () {
    var i;

    for (i=0; i < number; i += 1) {
        // create box
        addBox(newBox);
    }
}
```